# How can I get mysqldump to preserve the case of table names?

Tags: cross-platform, mysql

I'm attempting to migrate a database from a windows to a linux host.

Thanks!

Ashley

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not finding the the table names under linux mysql, coz its default is case-sensitive.
And for windows its case-insensitive.

I can't guess if ignoring case sensitivity works for you. But you can do by adding a line in my.conf. i.e. making mysql in linux to be case insensitive.

```
mysqlserver:~# vi /etc/mysql/my.cnf
...
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out the following links and see if that helps:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33898

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 0):

[Bug 33898](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33898) suggests `setting lower_case_table_names=2`.

Comment: From the docs: 

lower_case_table_names can only be configured when initializing the server. Changing the lower_case_table_names setting after the server is initialized is prohibited.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

This isn't a working solution to this issue.