# mysqldump problem with case sensitivity? Win->linux

Tags: windows, linux, mysql

When i dump a table with uppercase letters using mysqldump it comes out as lower case in my > dump.sql file. I found a report here in 2006, almost 4 years old http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19967

A [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999643/how-can-i-get-mysqldump-to-preserve-the-case-of-table-names) suggest making linux insensitive. I rather not if possible. Whats the easiest way to copy a win32 db into linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today I've had to make it so. I already have windows db in lower case and need to import to linux db with case sensitive table names, so the play with lowecase_table_names option in not an option :)

It looks that 'show tables' displays appropriately sorted table names and the dump have escaped table names with ` character. I've succesfully imported the database with following algorithm:

1. I have mydb.sql with lowercase windows dump
2. I started application to create database schema in Linux, with case sensitive names.

Then I've had lower case names in dump, and case sensitive names in mysql database. I converted the dump using sed & awk with following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYSQL="mysql -u root -p mydb"
FILE=mydb.sql

TMP1=`mktemp`
TMP2=`mktemp`

cp $FILE $TMP1

for TABLE in `echo "show tables" | $MYSQL`; do
  LCTABLE=`echo $TABLE| awk '{print tolower($0)}'`
  echo "$LCTABLE --> $TABLE"
  cat $TMP1 | sed "s/\`$LCTABLE\`/\`$TABLE\`/" > $TMP2
  cp $TMP2 $TMP1
done

cp $TMP1 $FILE.conv

rm $TMP1
rm $TMP2
```

And the dump has been converted properly. Everything works after import in Linux.

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 7):

According to the MySQL manuals, you only have a limited number of options:

> - Use lower_case_table_names=1 on all systems. The main disadvantage
>     with this is that when you use SHOW
>     TABLES or SHOW DATABASES, you do not
>     see the names in their original
>     lettercase.
> - Use lower_case_table_names=0 on Unix and lower_case_table_names=2 on
>     Windows. This preserves the lettercase
>     of database and table names. The
>     disadvantage of this is that you must
>     ensure that your statements always
>     refer to your database and table names
>     with the correct lettercase on
>     Windows. If you transfer your
>     statements to Unix, where lettercase
>     is significant, they do not work if
>     the lettercase is incorrect.
>
>   **Exception:** If you are using InnoDB tables and you are trying to
>     avoid these data transfer problems,
>     you should set lower_case_table_names
>     to 1 on all platforms to force names
>     to be converted to lowercase.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html for full details.

Comment: All of these options require the user to have gone back in time and configured their database lower_case_table_names option before the data was created.